# Power BI: Customer Active Streak

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, business-intelligence

I am trying to solve the following Issue in Power BI:
I have a fact-table containing sales and (among others) a dimension-table for customers. I have created several calculated columns for the customer dimension:

- [Average Days] between purchases
- [Date of last Purchase] by the customer
- [Customer Active] (True, if the customer has purchased anything in the last 365 days; False, if the customer has not purchased anything in the last 365 days.

Now I have to calculate the lenght of each customers "active streak", which should display the first date on which the customer has purchased something. There cannot be any gaps of more thand 365 days within an active streak.

Example:

- First purchase on January 1st 2018; Second purchase on September 2nd 2019 -> Active Streak since September 2nd 2019
- First purchase on January 1st 2018; Second purchase on December 3rd 2018; 3rd Purchase on June 4th 2019 -> Active streak since January 1st 2018

So basically, I am trying to find the last purchase before a gap of more than 365 days.

Any ideas of how to achieve this with DAX would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
The relevant tables look like this:

```
dCustomer (Customer Dimension):

[ContactSKey] (Primary Key)
[Contact Name]
[Contact City]
[Contact Insert Date]
...
[Last Purchase] (Calculated Column)
[Average Days between Purchases] (Calculated Column)
[Active Customer] (Calculated Column)

dSalesOrderInsertedDate (Date Table):
[DateSKey] (Primary Key)
[Sales_Order_Inserted Date] (Date Column)
[YearNumber]
...

fNoSalesDocument_Order (Fact Table):

[NoSalesDocumentSKey] (Primary Key)
[InsertedDateSKey] (Foreign Key of Date Table)
[ContactSKey] (Foreign Key of Customer Table)
[Item Amount]
[Item Quantity]
...
```

If you need any more information please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I can help you but I would like to see a basic table model of the tables and fields involved so the DAX you get is working, can you please add this to your question?

Comment: Your question does not specify if you need a calculated column or a measure. I assume this is a Calculated Column. I believe M Query is more relevant for this task.

Comment: Hi, I would prefer to create a Calculated Column with DAX, since I don't have direct access to the data source.